# PostgreSQL Client on SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, opensuse, suse

On an SUSE Linux server I need the tools psql, pg_dump and pg_restore, without the whole database server installation. Other distributions provide an postgresql-client package (Ubuntu) but I am unable to find anything similar for SUSE in the repostiroy https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/server:database:postgresql

Is there any other repository or any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

On Suse, the client utils are available in `postgresql<release>`, from the description: `postgresql - Basic Clients and Utilities for PostgreSQL`. This package does not contain any of the server code. The server code is contained within `postgresql<release>-server`, description: `postgresql-server - The Programs Needed to Create and Run a PostgreSQL Server`.